# Displaying FK's in Django forms as a select field properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two Django models:

```
from django.db import models


class Show(models.Model):
    show_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.show_title


class ShowDates(models.Model):
    show_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.show_date)
```

I am putting some `Shows` in the admin.py as well as some dates associated to the show.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Show, ShowDates


class ShowDatesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ShowDates
    extra = 0


class ShowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('show_title',)
    inlines = [ShowDatesInline]
admin.site.register(Show, ShowAdmin)
```

This is working great for entering in the shows and their respective dates. I am confused as to how to display the dates as a form select field that are related to the show. I currently have the following in my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core import urlresolvers

from .models import Show
from .forms import ShowDatesForm


def index(request, template):
    shows = Show.objects.all()
    return render(request, template, {
        'shows': shows,
    })
```

and here is the template using this code:

```
<table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Show Title</th>
                <th>Show Date(s)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for show in shows %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ show.show_title }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="." method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <select name="attributes" class="required" required>
                                <option value="">---- Please Select ----</option>
                                {% for show_date in show.showdates_set.all %}
                                    <option value="{{ show_date.show_date }}">
                                        {{ show_date.show_date }}
                                    </option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I feel this is the wrong way to go about it. Can someone lend a hand as to how to display the show dates related to the proper show so that when a user saves this form, the proper show and showdate save?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/), django will handle all of that for you.